# How to specific Datanote server on Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I am running a Hadoop cluster on 4 servers. I see that all servers has `TaskTracker` and `DataNone`

I start cluster with `hadoop/bin/start-all.sh`

I have 2 servers which have very litter Hardware Disk so I want these only run `TaskTracker`.

How should I config hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

`hadoop/bin/start-all.sh` actually just calls `hadoop/bin/start-dfs.sh` followed by `hadoop/bin/start-mapred.sh` so this provides a convenient way to use different settings for the two sets of daemons. The easiest way is to create a separate file, perhaps called hadoop/conf/datanodes, and then populate it with just the 2 servers that you want to be datanodes; presumably, you also have hadoop/conf/slaves which lists all 4 servers.

```
echo "my-datanode0" > hadoop/conf/datanodes
echo "my-datanode1" > hadoop/conf/datanodes
```

Then, run the two commands separately, note that there is no semicolon after the first assignment statement, as you need the environment variable to propagate into the underlying "slaves.sh" call:

```
HADOOP_SLAVES=hadoop/conf/datanodes ./hadoop/bin/start-dfs.sh
./hadoop/bin/start-mapred.sh
```

Go ahead and check port 50030 for your JobTracker's listing of TaskTrackers, then 50070 for your NameNode's listing of DataNodes, and you should be good to go.